# Why all objects and background is black in material viewport blender 2.79b

Tags: materials, 3d-view

I don't know why my blender 2.79 like this in Material Viewport.
[image]

But in Rendered Viewport Object Material showed
[image]

And when I click Object in Material Viewport like this
[image]

I have to reinstall blender and repair but still like this, is my graphic card isn't support? In blender 2.93 it's work normally

Comment: Difficult to say just based on screenshots, but Blender 2.79 is no longer receiving updates since 2019. If this is a bug in Blender 2.79 it won't be fixed. If you can, I would recommend that you use a current version.

Comment: IIRC you need to crank up the Environment Lighting in the World tab in the Properties editor, or everything is black.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, turned out it caused by GPU's driver. If you have AMD GPU like me, install latest version of PRO driver, or 22.5.1 version of Adrenalin edition driver.